# specifying an icon to be put on the desktop during installation

Tags: vb.net, winforms

when the user installs my vb.net application, i would like my icon (a shortcut) to be placed on the user's desktop. i am using vb express 2008, and am using the installer that it comes with. how do i specify an icon for this:?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create the setup project include the icon in the desktop folder:

Open Visual Studio

1. Create New Project->Project types = setup and deployment -> Setup Project
2. Add your application to the setup project (Right click on Application->Add)
3. Select "User's Desktop item"
4. Right-click the space
5. Browse to the applicaiton and add the shortcur.

**UPDATE** after comment:

You can make a manual installer that simply copies the exe file + a shortcut on the desktop (read [this](http://www.knowdotnet.com/articles/createshortcutondesktop.html)).

Comment: whats up shimmy we just returned from nachlaot

Comment: im unable to do as per your instructinos, vb 2008 express does not have SETUP AND DEPLOYMENT

Comment: @I__ suspect perhaps this isn't supported in limited versions of VS (Express?), I've updated my answer

Comment: @__ who are u, dont remember you, please contact me via [my blog](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shimmy/)

Comment: probably not but you should watch this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ObyX5AGYPPM&feature=related very very good

Comment: Cool! so how do you know me? Please let's continue this conversation [on chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7054/1325886-75500)

Comment: And BTW, if this answer helped you, please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's the same in vb 2008 express but in VS2008, you can right click on the setup project and choose View->File System, then in the User's Desktop folder add the shortcut. I believe the shortcut will pick up whatever icon you have specified for the output you select for that shortcut.  You can set up the icon by right clicking on your UI project, going to Properties->Application, then selecting the icon in the Icon drop down.

Again this is all VS2008 so not sure if its the same as vb 2008 express but hope it helps.

Comment: i selected an icon and upon installing it did not add it to desktop

Comment: Did you add the shortcut in the User's Desktop folder as well?

Comment: You need to add the shortcut into the "User's Desktop" folder like I have specified in the answer above.